# COPY failed: no source files were specified while docker-compose up

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, dockerfile

Dockerfile for express API is like it:

```
FROM node:10.15.3

MAINTAINER AshishkrGoyal <ashish.goyal@algoscale.com>

#RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

#define working dir
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

#available package.json, package-lock.json as well
COPY package*.json ./

#install all dependencies listed in package.json
RUN npm install

#copy all the source code to working dir
COPY . .

#mapping of port to docker daemon
EXPOSE 3000

#command in the form of array
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml is like as shown below:

```
#specify the docker-compose version
version: '3.0'

services:
#specify all the services 
  angular: #it is frontend service container name
    build: public #dockerfile directory
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"

  express: #it is backend service container name
    build: server #dockerfile directory
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - database

  database: #it is elastc search service container name
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.0
    ports:
        - "9200:9200"
```

While running command docker-compose up i am getting following error:
**ERROR: Service 'express' failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified**

Please help me in solving this error.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It will copy all the code to the working directory as in my case it is /usr/src/app

Comment: Is there a file matching `package*.json` within the server directory? Do you have a `.dockerignore` file, and if so, what are the contents? Can you show the entire build output up to the failure so we can see which step is failing since you have two COPY commands?

Comment: @SherloxFR the copy source is the build context, the destination is the image, so each `.` is for a different location.

Answer (score 2):

please check if your `.gitignore` file has ignored your source file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#copy all the source code to working dir
COPY . .
```

This will copy the current dir of the *host* as part of the image creation process. Is `docker-compose up ...` being executed from the root of the Express project? Otherwise the Express projects files would not be found when the image is being created.

Comment: Yes,  i am running docker-compose up from the root of the project

Comment: Perfect. Checkout the 'build context' configuration of docker-compose. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ For Express provide the sub-dir name that is the 'root' of the Express project inside the over-all docker project.